# Simple JavaScript Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, onclick

Hi I have a simple JavaScript question, I haven't used JavaScript for a while, so was wondering if you could help.

```
<?php
$sizeChartIcon= Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."size-charts/size-icon.gif"; ?>

<a onclick="$('size-chart').show();"><?php echo '<img src="'.$sizeChartIcon.'" alt="size chart">' ; ?></a> 

<div id="size-chart" style="display:none;"> <?php echo  Mage::app() ->getLayout() ->createBlock('cms/block') ->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('size_chart_template')) ->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

This shows the static block if you click on the sizeChartIcon, but it stays open, how would I hide it again if the customer was to click on the icon again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this instead of show()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Source: http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/